# Subcommands in Python Bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

How to create sub commands in python bot.

```
   @bot.group(pass_context=True)
        async def First(ctx):
            if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
                await bot.say('Invalid sub command passed...')

        @First.command(pass_context=True)
        async def Second(ctx):
            msg = 'Finally got success {0.author.mention}'.format(ctx.message)
            await bot.say(msg)
```

Comment: The mistake seems to lie in the indentation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make `Second` a group too.

```
@bot.group(pass_context=True)
async def First(ctx):
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
        await bot.say('Invalid sub command passed...')

@First.group(pass_context=True)
async def Second(ctx):
    if ctx.invoked_subcommand is Second:
        await bot.say('Invalid sub command passed...')

@Second.command(pass_context=True)
async def Third(ctx):
    msg = 'Finally got success {0.author.mention}'.format(ctx.message)
    await bot.say(msg)
```

Comment: Thank you Patrick, but still i can't get what i need. If i type `?First` i get `Invalid sub command passed` but when i try `?First Second` or `?First Second Third` i get error `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "firstsecond" is not found` and `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "firstsecondthird" is not found`

Comment: Do you have an `on_message` event that is mutating the messages before they're processed?

Comment: yes i have 1 `on_message`  but i used `await bot.process_commands(message)`

Comment: Are you changing `message` before passing it?  That's the only way I can think of to get from `?First Second` to `firstsecond`

Comment: Hi.. Patrick yes your code worked. actually i did some typo mistake so i got error. now its working perfect thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Subcommands are commands that are part of a group.  To make a group, use this:
(replace client with whatever you call your client/bot)

```
@client.group(invoke_without_command=True)
async def parent_command(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Parent command!")
```

To make a command for that group, do something like this:

```
@parent_command.command()
async def child_command(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Child command!")
```

**invoke_without_command=True** will make it so that when you run a subcommand, the parent command will not invoke, or run (trigger if you call it that ;) )

Also you can make subgroups, just read the answer above for better explanation.